# ERC20 token transfer failed When getting called by a smart contract

Tags: remix, erc-20, error, sepolia

I'm developing a smart contract in Remix, and it is compiling correctly, but every time I try to execute functions related to the  `transfer` function from my token ERC-20, it returns me an error saying that the execution was reverted.

[Contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x32D28885b02Cf0020e5d06EEe6A27D3Ef2A52Ebe) address: `0x32D28885b02Cf0020e5d06EEe6A27D3Ef2A52Ebe`

[Token](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x138F1A0e20af9A0E56fC7d7b23Cd5c394631B19a) address: `0x138F1A0e20af9A0E56fC7d7b23Cd5c394631B19a`

One of the functions I'm trying to execute:

```js
       function transferirTokens(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public {
       require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
            
            token.transfer(receiver, numTokens);
        }
```

I'm creating the contract in the testnet Sepolia, with my Metamask account with 5 Sepolia ETH as the `msg.sender`.

I've been trying a lot of things, but I'm a bit desperate. Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

The contract:

```js
        // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
    
    import "./TOKEN.sol"; 
    
    contract SistemaRecompenses {
        JaumeCallisToken public token; 
        address public owner; 
        
    
        constructor(address tokenAddress) {
            token = JaumeCallisToken(tokenAddress); 
            owner = msg.sender; 
        }
    
        // Estructura per emmagatzemar les dades de l'alumne
        struct Alumne {
            int256 tokens; 
            uint256 Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies; 
            uint256 incidencies; 
            uint256 faltes; 
            uint256 retards; 
            uint256 RecompensaBar; 
            uint256 RecompensaSortidaTrimestral; 
            uint256 RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs; 
            uint256 RecompensaBiblioteca;
            uint256 RecompensaTemaClasse;
            
            mapping(string => uint256) assignatures; // Balanç de tokens per assignatura
        }
    
        mapping(address => Alumne) public alumnes; // Mapping amb les dades de cada alumne
        address[] public adrecesAlumnes; // Llista d'adreces d'alumnes
    
        // Afegir un alumne a la llista d'adreces
        function afegirAlumne(address alumne) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
        adrecesAlumnes.push(alumne);
        
    }
         // Funció per aconseguir el totalSupply 
        function obtenirTotalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
            require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
            return token.totalSupply();
        }
    
        // Funció per transferir tokens JC des de l'adreça del creador del contracte
        function transferirTokens(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public {
       require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
            
            token.transfer(receiver, numTokens);
        }
    
        // Funció per transferir els tokens perduts a l'adreça del creador del contracte
        function transferirTokensPerduts(uint256 numTokens) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
            
            token.transfer(owner, numTokens);
        }
    
    
        // Funció per iniciar el trimestre i donar 50 tokens a tots els alumnes
        function iniciarTrimestre() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner,"Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio");
       
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < adrecesAlumnes.length; i++) {
            address alumne = adrecesAlumnes[i];
            transferirTokens(alumne, 50000000000000000000);
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne]; 
            alumneData.tokens += 50; 
            
            
        }
    }
        // Funció per avaluació de l'alumne
        function avaluarAlumne(address alumne, string memory assignatura, uint256 qualificacio) public {
            require(qualificacio >= 0 && qualificacio <= 10, unicode"Qualificació no vàlida");
    
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
    
            if (qualificacio >= 9) {
                alumneData.tokens += 10;
                transferirTokens(alumne, 10000000000000000000);
            } else if (qualificacio >= 7) {
                alumneData.tokens += 5;
                transferirTokens(alumne, 50000000000000000000);
            } else if (qualificacio < 5) {
                alumneData.tokens -= 5;
                alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies += 5;
                transferirTokensPerduts(5000000000000000000);
            }
    
            
            alumneData.assignatures[assignatura] += uint256 (qualificacio);
        }
    
        // Funció per registrar una incidència
        function registrarIncidencia(address alumne) public {
    
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
    
            if (alumneData.tokens >= 35) {
                alumneData.tokens -= 5;
                alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies += 5;
                transferirTokensPerduts(5000000000000000000);
            } 
    
            // Incrementa el comptador d'incidències
            alumneData.incidencies++;
        }
    
        // Funció per registrar una falta
        function registrarFalta(address alumne) public {
    
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
    
            // Incrementa el comptador de faltes
            alumneData.faltes++;
    
            
            if (alumneData.faltes % 3 == 0) {
                registrarIncidencia(alumne);
            }
        }
    
        // Funció per registrar un retard
        function registrarRetard(address alumne) public {
    
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
    
            // Incrementa el comptador de retards
            alumneData.retards++;
    
            
            if (alumneData.retards % 3 == 0) {
                registrarIncidencia(alumne);
            }
        }
    
        // Funció per aconseguir les dades d'un alumne
        function obtenirDadesAlumne(address alumne) public view returns (int256 tokens,uint256 Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies, uint256 incidencies, uint256 faltes, uint256 retards,uint256 RecompensaBar, uint256 RecompensaSortidaTrimestral, uint256 RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs, uint256 RecompensaBiblioteca, uint256 RecompensaTemaClasse) {
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
            return (alumneData.tokens, alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies, alumneData.incidencies, alumneData.faltes, alumneData.retards, alumneData.RecompensaBar, alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral,alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs, alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca, alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse);
        }
    
        // Funció per canviar recompensa
        function canviarRecompensa(address alumne, uint256 opcio) public {
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
            require(opcio >= 1 && opcio <= 5, unicode"Opció no vàlida");
    
            
            uint8[5] memory preus = [20, 0, 0, 60, 60];
    
            require(int256 (alumneData.tokens) >= int8 (preus[opcio - 1]), "Tokens insuficients");
    
            alumneData.tokens -= int8 (preus[opcio - 1]);
    
            // Aplica la recompensa segons l'opció triada
            if (opcio == 1) {
                // Descompte al bar
                // Conversió de 20 JCTokens = 1 euro
                alumneData.RecompensaBar += 1;
                transferirTokensPerduts(20000000000000000000);
            } else if (opcio == 2) {
                // Assistència a sortida escolar (màxim 30 JCTokens restats)
                require(alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies <= 30, "Has restat masses tokens, no pots participar a la sortida");
                alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral += 1;
            } else if (opcio == 3) {
                // Assistència a sortida de final de curs (màxim 120 JCTokens restats)
                require(alumneData.Tokens_Restats_Per_Suspensos_o_Incidencies <= 120, "Has restat masses tokens, no pots participar a la sortida");
                alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs += 1;
            } else if (opcio == 4) {
                // Permis per anar a la biblioteca durant els patis (60 JCTokens)
                alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca += 1;
                transferirTokensPerduts(60000000000000000000);
            } else if (opcio == 5) {
                // Triar el tema de classe d'una tutoria (60 JCTokens)
                alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse += 1;
                transferirTokensPerduts(60000000000000000000);
            } 
        }
        // Funció per canviar recompensa (aquesta seria la funció que cridaria algun professor o encarregat del bar per gastar la recompensa de l'alumne)
        function UtilitzarRecompensa(address alumne, uint256 opcio) public {
            Alumne storage alumneData = alumnes[alumne];
            require(opcio >= 1 && opcio <= 5, unicode"Opció no vàlida");
    
            if (opcio == 1) {
                // Descompte al bar
                // Conversió de 20 JCTokens = 1 euro
                require(alumneData.RecompensaBar >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
                alumneData.RecompensaBar -= 1;
            } else if (opcio == 2) {
                require(alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
                alumneData.RecompensaSortidaTrimestral -= 1;
            } else if (opcio == 3) {
                // Assistència a sortida de final de curs (mínim 120 JCTokens)
                require(alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
                alumneData.RecompensaSortidaFinalCurs -= 1;
            } else if (opcio == 4) {
                // Permis per anar a la biblioteca durant els patis (60 JCTokens)
                require(alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
                alumneData.RecompensaBiblioteca -= 1;
            } else if (opcio == 5) {
                // Triar el tema de classe d'una tutoria (60 JCTokens)
                require(alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse >=1,"Obten primer la recompensa");
                alumneData.RecompensaTemaClasse -= 1;
            } 
        }
    }


The token contract: 

    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
    
    interface IERC20 {
    
        function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
        function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
        function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    
        function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
        function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
        function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    
    
        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
        event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    }
    
    
    contract JaumeCallisToken is IERC20 {
        using SafeMath for uint256;
    
        string public constant name = "JaumeCallisToken";
        string public constant symbol = "JC";
        uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    
        mapping(address => uint256) balances;
        mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    
        uint256 private totalSupply_ = 21000000*10**uint256(decimals);
    
        constructor(){
            balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
        }
    
        function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
            return totalSupply_;
        }
    
        function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
            return balances[tokenOwner];
        }
    
    
        function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    
            require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
            balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
            balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
            return true;
    
        }
    
        function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
            allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
            return true;
        }
    
        function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
            return allowed[owner][delegate];
        }
    
        function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
    
            require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
            require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);
    
            balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
            allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
            balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
            emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
            return true;
    
        }
    }
    
    library SafeMath {
        function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
          assert(b <= a);
          return a - b;
        }
    
        function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
          uint256 c = a + b;
          assert(c >= a);
          return c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the contract, there can be multiple reasons. Can't find out just looking at the function.

Comment: Yes please include more information. A failing tx hash if you have it. Make sure any contracts moving tokens have the allowance to do it by sending any required approvals.

Comment: okay, here's the two contracts

Comment: Can you provide the tx hash of the failed `Transfer()`? I only see a successful `Transfer()` as the most recent tx

Comment: 0xc662b3633e2ec14c4b5c6566d3bb45b701286c388d8acd3b8b652e73a18f20bf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transfer` function sends tokens from the caller to the receiver and not from `msg.sender`.

The function you wrote is called by the contract itself, and since the contract has no tokens, the function reverts.

You should make `transferFrom` instead of `transfer`, here is an example.

```js
  function transferirTokens(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public  {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "Nomes el creador pot executar aquesta funcio"
    );

    token.transferFrom(msg.sender,receiver, numTokens); // edited line
  }
```

Keep in mind that your contract should have approval to spend your tokens (msg.sender) tokens. You should fire the approve function before firing `transferirTokens` function.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I understand. Now it works all correctly! Thank you very much!

Comment: If the problem is solved, you can mark the answer as correct for future visitors. And I will modify the question to be related to that problem.